# Adapt the extend selection in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, selection

Everyone knows that when you select some text in IntelliJ and press Ctrl+w your selection is expanded.

However,

you're kinda stuck on the presets for this:

when you have following code:

```
<a4j:commandButton execute="@form" render="tableProperties" 
       value="#{cjr_main.addExtractType}" 
       action="#{ExtractTypesBean.addExtractType()}" 
       styleClass="bigButton"                        
       oncomplete="setLineAdded();"/>
```

and "Line" is selected but the method setLineAdded() is not yet defined you'd want "setLineAdded()" to be selected after hitting ctrl+w a couple of times.

However

Once "setLineAdded" is selected, and you press ctrl + w the whole tag is selected in stead of the accompanying "()"'s...

Is there a way to get this behavior? 
(without writing a whole IntelliJ plugin just for this?)

best regards,

S.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the behavior of extend selection is controlled by code and is not configurable by users. You can indeed write a plugin to change the behavior.